# How to put action button icon inside address/url bar of Firefox add-ons

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

According to Firefox addons sdk's [UI/Button/Action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action) low level API I can perfectly put the extension icon on the toolbar. Actually By default, the button appears in the Firefox toolbar.

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
    id: "XXXX",
    label: "XXXXXXYYYYY",
    icon: {
        "16": "./icon-16.png",
        "32": "./icon-32.png",
        "64": "./icon-64.png"
    },
onClick: handleClick
});
```

I can't see any options there in the API documentation to put the icon else where.

But few FF extensions did that. I want to put the extension icon inside the browser's address bar like the following screenshot:

[image]

Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Did you try the code I provided? I just tested it in Australis and it still works.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that perfoms what @ZER0 describes. <s>I haven't tested this in Australis, but I think it should still work</s> I have tested it, and it does work.

```
var loadUrlbarButton = function(doc, urlBtnClick) {
    var urlBarIcons = doc.getElementById('urlbar-icons')
    var btn = doc.createElement('toolbarbutton');
    btn.setAttribute('id', 'my-id');
    btn.setAttribute('image', require('sdk/self').data.url('my-icon.png'));
    btn.addEventListener('command', urlBtnClick, false);
    urlBarIcons.appendChild(btn);
    return btn;
}

var doc = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document;

var onBtnClick = function(event) {
    //do something when URL bar button is clicked
}

var urlbarButton = loadUrlbarButton(doc, onBtnClick);
```

Comment: You are a stud. Is there an easy way to modify the image that the button uses on the fly from an external function?

Comment: Yeah, just call `urlbarButton.setAttribute('image', data.url('my-activated-icon.png'));`

Comment: Good stuff! Thank you so much! Is there a way to refresh the button after changing it? That part doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: No worries. Just think of the browser as you would a web page. Once you have access to an element, you can add a child, a listener, some CSS… Have a look at the [DOM inspector extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) if you want to poke around the browser/chrome a little more.

Comment: The built-in browser toolbox actually performs the same function as that extension, so it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible with Add-on SDK or Customizable UI APIs; you have basically to do that manually – it means, track all the browser windows, and append a XUL DOM node in the right place, and handle the click.

Such feature was actually planned, but because in the new Australis interface the UX team decided to make the location bar cleaner, removing all the icons – notice that also the bookmark star icon was moved outside – it got de-prioritized. We have a bug, however, and I have a prototype of such functionality that I'd like to land unless UX has still strong feeling about that.
If that would be the case, I'll probably release such module as 3rd party module.